# I want my flutter app to launch automatically once the android device boots up

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to know how I can automatically launch a Flutter app once a device boots up. I know It's possible in Native Android apps with java and kotlin but my app is based on flutter.

My use case is that I have an Android Auto like interface app designed for tablets that opens up once the device boots

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: When an Android device powers on the app opens automatically. that is what I am asking

Comment: Yes, you can do it on flutter. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/70795926/11445944

Answer (score 0):

What you can consider doing here is by pushing a [local notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) that when clicked, opens the app. App processes can be run in the background automatically by using [auto_start_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_start_flutter) and by requesting for the required permissions using `getAutoStartPermission();`. Note that this is currently only available for Android.

Launching an app automatically without user consent isn't something that's allowed for security reasons. You may also want to check how apps are developed for [Android Auto](https://developer.android.com/training/cars).