# How to start Flutter app on system startup?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making a Flutter app which I want to make it start automatically on system boot. So far, I have tried [autostart](https://pub.dev/packages/autostart) and [flutter_boot_startup](https://github.com/oatpano/flutter_boot_startup) but these packages are outdated and they don't work (using Samsung Tab A, Android 10 - iOS is not important for me).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: try Android Power Tools

Comment: try the answer below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53715839/autostart-on-boot-completed-for-flutter-application-based-on-android-example-not

Comment: I saw that question, tried but it is not working. App is running fine, but it is not starting automatically when I restart my tablet

Comment: Were you able to achieve it? @Teemo

Answer (score 1):

Create a new java class in your `android/src/main/java/<package-name>/..` folder (same folder as MainActivity.java)

Call it whatever you want e.g. BootBroadcastReceiver.java

```
package <your package name here>;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class BootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

add this android permission to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

add this at the bottom of the `<application ... />` object inside your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" 
android:name=".BootBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

The app needs to opened at least once before this will work.

this works for me on ATV devices and Acer/Lenovo tablets

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, one option that you can try is by pushing a local notification. You can consider using the package [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications). You could also check out [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74683629/8342742) which is related to your question.

> What you can consider doing here is by pushing a [local
> notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)
> that when clicked, opens the app. App processes can be run in the
> background automatically by using
> [auto_start_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_start_flutter) and
> by requesting for the required permissions using
> `getAutoStartPermission()`;. Note that this is currently only
> available for Android.