# Flutter app BOOT_COMPLETED receiver doesn't work

Tags: android, flutter

There have been many questions like this before, and I've tried to implement the answers but it doesn't work on Android 11. I want my flutter app will be started/opened automatically after booting was completed.

this is my receiver `MainActivityReceiver.kt`

```
package com.mypackage

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

class MainActivityReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) {
            val i = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            context.startActivity(i)
        }
    }
}
```

and I added some code on `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

```
<receiver
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:name="com.myPackage.MainActivityReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

  </receiver>
```

**EDIT**

I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/63250729/11445944, but how to implement it on flutter?.
How to add this code on flutter `MainActivity.kt`

```
if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(getApplicationContext())) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);

            myIntent.setData(uri);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, REQUEST_OVERLAY_PERMISSIONS);
            return;
        }
```

I've added it on my MainActivity.kt

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(getApplicationContext())) {
            val myIntent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION)
            val uri: Uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null)
            myIntent.setData(uri)
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, REQUEST_OVERLAY_PERMISSIONS)
            return
        }
    }
```

And I got the error on build

```
[   +2 ms] e: project_path/app/MainActivity.kt: (32, 5): 'onCreate' overrides nothing
[  +24 ms] e: project_path/app/src/main/kotlin/package/MainActivity.kt: (32, 47): Unresolved reference: Bundle
[   +7 ms] e: project_path/app/src/main/kotlin/package/MainActivity.kt: (34, 14): Unresolved reference: Settings
[   +3 ms] e: project_path/app/src/main/kotlin/package/MainActivity.kt: (35, 35): Unresolved reference: Settings
[   +3 ms] e: project_path/app/src/main/kotlin/MainActivity.kt: (38, 46): Unresolved reference:
REQUEST_OVERLAY_PERMISSIONS
```

**SOLVED**

The error was gone after I import 2 lines code

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.Settings
```

and don't forget to initialize `var REQUEST_OVERLAY_PERMISSIONS = 100`. Now my app run automatically after booting was completed on Android 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Flutter you need to add in manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

then onCreate of `MainActivity.kt` file

```
 if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(getApplicationContext())) {
            val myIntent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION)
            val uri: Uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null)
            myIntent.setData(uri)
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, REQUEST_OVERLAY_PERMISSIONS)
            return
        }
```

and rest will be same for receiver.

Edit.....

For Android - 11 changes.
you need to open settings for that system overlay permission:

```
startActivityForResult(
    Intent(
        Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
        Uri.parse("package:$packageName")
    ),
    REQUEST_OVERDRAW_PERMISSION_CODE
)
```

Check this out : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/permissions#manage_overlay

Comment: I've tried to add that code, but I got an error. See my edit above.

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak : same error are you getting ?

Comment: Yes, I get same error. The error occured on build,

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak : Check my edited answer. hope this will help you. and please  uninstall old app and try to install new one and do flutter clean and check again

Comment: Thanks, your answer is same as my code in edit and I've tried before but got an error. And the error is gone after I add some import code like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70980466/11445944

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Android 10 (API 29), there are [restrictions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) on directly starting activities from the background in order to minimize user interruptions. See if your application starts on bootup if you use API 28 or below. As a possible compromise, you can display a high priority notification which opens the application when the user clicks it.

Comment: I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/63250729/11445944, but how to implement it on flutter?. It works on android 10.

Comment: You'd have to implement a `BroadcastReceiver` which will pick up when the phone boots up. In the `onReceive` method of the receiver, place the code which you currently have in your `onCreate` method.