# Flutter 'onCreate' overrides nothing

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I want to add some kotlin code on my flutter app. I add onCreate function on **project_name/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/app/MainActivity.kt**.

This is my full `MainActivity.kt`

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
import android.os.Environment
import android.net.Uri

import android.content.Intent

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private val channel = "externalStorage";
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, channel).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            when (call.method) {
                "getExternalStorageDirectory" ->
                    result.success(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString())
                "getExternalStoragePublicDirectory" -> {
                    val type = call.argument<String>("type")
                    result.success(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(type).toString())
                }
                else -> result.notImplemented()
            }
        }

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(getApplicationContext())) {
            val myIntent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION)
            val uri: Uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null)
            myIntent.setData(uri)
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, REQUEST_OVERLAY_PERMISSIONS)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

then I got this error on my build

```
'onCreate' overrides nothing
Unresolved reference: Settings
Unresolved reference: Settings
Unresolved reference:
REQUEST_OVERLAY_PERMISSIONS
```

Do I need to import some code?

Comment: Do you have `class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()` ?

Comment: My `MainActivity` is like this `class MainActivity: FlutterActivity()`

Comment: @ADM you can see my full code above. I've edited my code.

Comment: In Andriod Studio, on the Code menu, click Override methods or <Ctrl+O>. Alternatively, you can right-click anywhere in the class file, then click Generate or <Alt+Insert>, and select Override methods to make IDE generate those for you.

Comment: @bylazy this is flutter project, there is no suggestion for  `MainActivity.kt`. If I click <Ctrl+O> I have 3 override options : hashCode, equals, toString() and I got same error for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer. I need to import some code to add `onCreate` method.

1. `import android.os.Bundle` for `Bundle` parameter. See [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/Bundle) link.
2. `import android.provider.Settings` because I use `Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION`. See [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings) link.
3. I forgot to add `var REQUEST_OVERLAY_PERMISSIONS = 100`

And now it works.