# Flutter awesome_notifications and local_notifications schedule was remove after device rebooted

Tags: android, flutter, localnotification, reboot, awesome-notifications

Schedule notifications doesn't show after I reboot my device.

I tried to this following steps but still not working for me.
[Flutter app BOOT_COMPLETED receiver doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70795926/flutter-app-boot-completed-receiver-doesnt-work)

Device : Oppo A92
Android version : 11

Though emulator works fine, but in physical device doesn't. Does anyone here know how to fix it ?

Btw I started creating mobile app from flutter so I don't have any experience in native development.

AndroidManifest.xml
[image: AndroidManifest.xml]

MainActivity.kt
[image: MainActivity.kt]

ServiceStartup.kt
[image: ServiceStartup.kt]